# Simple CSS DIV Tab image change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a very silly issue here. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, or am overlooking something.

I have a set of tabs that I would like to change the background image each time you click on a new tab link. Just a simple background image change. Can't seem to get the document.getElementById to work. I think I'm not targeting it correctly.

Excuse the sloppiness of the code, still organizing it. No JS was implemented.

Any help at getting this working would be great!

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 outline: none;
 font-weight: normal;
}

body {
 background: #3498DB;
}

a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*header {
 color: #yellow;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 140px;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}*/

header h1{
 margin-top: 100px;
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-weight: 100;
}

header a{
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.copyright {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

/* Tabs Start */

.ease {
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
   -o-transition: all .5s;
   transition: all .5s;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs {
 background-color:red;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tabs > input,
.tabs > span {
 width: 20%;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}

.tabs > input {
 cursor: pointer;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
}

.tabs > span {
 background: #deeab4;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs > span i,
.tabs > span {
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
   -o-transition: all .5s;
   transition: all .5s;
}

.tabs > input:hover + span {
 background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.tabs > input:checked + span {
 background: #95d600;
}

.tabs > input:checked + span,
.tabs > input:hover + span {
 color: #fff;
}

#tab-1, #tab-1 + span {
 left: 0;
}

#tab-2, #tab-2 + span {
 left: 20%;
}

#tab-3, #tab-3 + span {
 left: 40%;
}

#tab-4, #tab-4 + span {
 left: 60%;
}

#tab-5, #tab-5 + span {
 left: 80%;
}

/*.tab-content {
 padding: 80px 20px 20px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 388px;
}*/


.tab-content section {
 width: 100%;
 display: none;

}

.tab-content section h1 {
 margin-top: 15px;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
}

#tab-1:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-1  {
 display: block;
}

#tab-2:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-2  {
 display:block;
}

#tab-3:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-3  {
 display: block;
}

#tab-4:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-4  {
 display: block;
}

#tab-5:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-5  {
 display: block;
}

/* effect-1 */

.effect-1 > input:checked + span {
 background: #8cd600;
}

/* Boxes */

.box60-1 {
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 height:317px;
 display:block;
 background-color:#FFF;
    background: rgb(204, 204, 204); /* older browsers */
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
 
}

.box40-2 {
 float:left;
 width:40%;
 height:317px;
 display:block;
 background-color:#FFF;
    background: rgb(204, 204, 204); /* older browsers */
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
 
 
}


.box60-1 strong, .box40-2 strong {
 font-weight:bolder;
 font-size: 26px;
 
}

.box60-1 p, .box40-2 p {
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 22px;
 
}




/* Picture Change */
.tab-content {
 background-image:url(picture-1.jpg);
 padding: 80px 20px 20px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 388px;
}

.pic1 {
 background-image:url(picture-1.jpg);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 388px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}

.pic2 {
 background-image:url(picture-2.jpg);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 388px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;

}

.pic3 {
 background-image:url(picture-3.jpg);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 388px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;

}


.pic4 {
 background-image:url(picture-4.jpg);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 388px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;

}

.pic5 {
 background-image:url(picture-5.jpg);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 388px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;

}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
<!-- tab-title -->
   <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-effect-1" checked="checked">
   <span><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('tab-content').className='pic1'">Call Center</a></span>

   <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-effect-1">
   <span><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('tab-content').className='pic2'">Self-Service</a></span>

   <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-effect-1">
   <span><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('tab-content').className='pic3'">Customer Outreach</a></span>

   <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-effect-1">
   <span><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('tab-content').className='pic4'">Workforce Optimization</a></span>
   
   <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-effect-1">
   <span style="line-height:20px; padding-top:10px;"><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('tab-content').className='pic5'">Cloud Infrastructure<br>and Platforms</a></span>


<!-- tab-content -->
   <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <section id="tab-item-1">
     <div class="box60-1">
                    <p><strong>blah <br>
blah blah</strong></p>
<p>hello good sir</p>
                    </div>
    </section>
    <section id="tab-item-2">
     <h1>Two</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="tab-item-3">
     <h1>Three</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="tab-item-4">
     <h1>Four</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="tab-item-5">
     <h1>Five</h1>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: if no JS was implimented why did you say "Can't seem to get the document.getElementById to work. I think I'm not targeting it correctly."?

Comment: Was going off of this site, [link]http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/122011-onclick-change-div-background-image.html[/link

Comment: @jaycss88, If you see the post you linked, there is a script they tell to include as well.

Comment: What just happened to the answers that were posted here? I'm trying to target the .tab-content only to change image. Not the <section>

Comment: One answer was deleted by its author. You should really look into separation of concerns (using event handlers instead of putting JS in your HTML).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking the onclick out of the anchor tag (it is not being read because what your actually clicking on to change tabs in the input) and placing an onchange in the input itself. You will also change the classnames of each to read tab-content pic1, tab-content pic2, etc. otherwise the tab-content class gets replaced totally.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  background: #3498DB;
}

input {
  z-index: -1;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

header a {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.copyright {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}


/* Tabs Start */

.ease {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tabs > input,
.tabs > span {
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.tabs > input {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}

.tabs > span {
  background: #deeab4;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs > span i,
.tabs > span {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.tabs > input:hover + span {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.tabs > input:checked + span {
  background: #95d600;
}

.tabs > input:checked + span,
.tabs > input:hover + span {
  color: #fff;
}

#tab-1,
#tab-1 + span {
  left: 0;
}

#tab-2,
#tab-2 + span {
  left: 20%;
}

#tab-3,
#tab-3 + span {
  left: 40%;
}

#tab-4,
#tab-4 + span {
  left: 60%;
}

#tab-5,
#tab-5 + span {
  left: 80%;
}


/*.tab-content {
padding: 80px 20px 20px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 388px;
}*/

.tab-content section {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.tab-content section h1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

#tab-1:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-1 {
  display: block;
}

#tab-2:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-2 {
  display: block;
}

#tab-3:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-3 {
  display: block;
}

#tab-4:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-4 {
  display: block;
}

#tab-5:checked ~ .tab-content #tab-item-5 {
  display: block;
}


/* effect-1 */

.effect-1 > input:checked + span {
  background: #8cd600;
}


/* Boxes */

.box60-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 317px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  /* older browsers */
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
}

.box40-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 317px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  /* older browsers */
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
}

.box60-1 strong,
.box40-2 strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.box60-1 p,
.box40-2 p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* Picture Change */

.tab-content {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/1);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 388px;
}

.pic1 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/1);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 388px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}

.pic2 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/2);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 388px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}

.pic3 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/3);
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 388px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
<!-- tab-title -->
<input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-effect-1" checked="checked" onclick="document.getElementById('tabContent').className='pic1'">
<span><a href="#">Call Center</a></span>

<input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-effect-1" onclick="document.getElementById('tabContent').className='pic2'">
<span><a href="#">Self-Service</a></span>

<input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-effect-1" onclick="document.getElementById('tabContent').className='pic3'">
<span><a href="#">Customer Outreach</a></span>

<!-- tab-content -->
<div id="tabContent" class="tab-content">
  <section id="tab-item-1">
    <div class="box60-1">
      <p><strong>blah <br>
blah blah</strong></p>
      <p>hello good sir</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-item-2">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-item-3">
    <h1>Three</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-item-4">
    <h1>Four</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-item-5">
    <h1>Five</h1>
  </section>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! New to this site, I appreciate the help.